# How to restrict access users who are not an author to post on django generic editing views?

Tags: python, django

Building a website with referring to a book, I made a blog application.
And I found even nonauthors can edit/delete the post which they didn't write. So I've tried to fix it in many ways but failed so far.

Here are my codes.

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('TITLE', max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField('SLUG', unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
    description = models.CharField('DESCRIPTION', max_length=100, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField('CONTENT')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('Create Date', auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField('Modify Date', auto_now=True)
    tag = TagField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-modify_date',) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=(self.slug,))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, edit.UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'slug', 'description', 'content', 'tag']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(PostUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, edit.DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(PostDeleteView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Below is the only code which worked and I found it in docs(Using FormMixin with DetailView)

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not ((request.user==Post.author) or request.user.is_superuser):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

It worked, in some points, cuz it returns HttpResponseForbidden if nonauthor try to click "submit" in update form. However, what I want is that nonauthor cannot even access to update page. 
I also found the way to customize dispatch() in stackoverflow but it didn't work. 
I'm not sure whether it is proper in Django to use `{% if not user == object.author %}{% else %}{% endif %}` on templates like in PHP.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dispatch` method is the right place to do this because it will affect all requests. As you've noticed, putting access control code in the `post` method doesn't affect `GET` requests.

How did you try to override `dispatch`? Because something like this should work:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, edit.UpdateView):
    #
    # All of your other view code here....
    #
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        handler = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        user = request.user
        post = self.get_object()
        if not (post.author == user or user.is_superuser):
            raise PermissionDenied
        return handler
```

If you're supporting Python2 you'll have to change the `super()` call to `super(PostUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Oh my god it worked! I checked the dispatch() method that I'd written down and I could see I definitely did wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: Before your answer posted, I had tried {% if not user == object.author %} with customtag to return "No Permission" on templates and it also worked. Is is proper for Django?

Comment: No, templates are the wrong place to do access control. For one thing, it doesn't stop people from constructing a POST and sending it to your view's URL, bypassing the template.

Comment: I've got it now! Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help.